# Regex - How can I validate an amount that allows 20 digits, multiple commas, and one dot?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can we validate a String/Amount that allows,

- 20 digits
- Multiple commas(can be placed multiple times, but not first char or after the dot)
- One dot

Should pass,

1. 1231231231.123
2. 1,231,231,231.123
3. 123123,1,231.123

Should Fail,

1. 12312312.31.123
2. 1,231,231,231.12,3
3. ,123123,1,231.123

Edited:

I've tried `^(\d+)?^(,+)?([.]?\d{0,20})?$` this regex.

Comment: [create a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is the dot always followed by exactly 3 numbers (and perhaps commas)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No! commas can be put anywhere (except as a first char or after the dot) - not 3 numbers rule.

Comment: question has been updated. ;)

Comment: Use this to help refine your regex: regexr.com

Comment: @SeanKendle thank you for your concern- actually I came from there after having trouble to fix it.

Comment: 1. Can the dot be at the beginning or end of the string? 2. Can a dot or a comma follow a comma? 3. Does “20 digits” mean up to 20 digits or exactly 20 digits? 4. Does “1 dot” mean at most 1 dot or exactly 1 dot? 5. Does "multiple commas” mean zero or more, one or more or two or more commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){1,20}$)\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9tk3w/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){1,20}$)`: Positive lookahead to ensure that we have 1 to 20 digits in input
- `\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?`: Start with 1+ digits and end with 1+ digits and allow multiple commas and single dot
- `$`: End

Comment: Thank you! that's what I needed.

Comment: you didn't put it in the requirements, but should 123,,,,,,.99 not fail the test? (apart from the length)